# workbench is necessary for the creating local database form the script file

Tags: mysql, database, sqlyog

i downloaded Mysql server for win64-bit machine from 
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=409022 this link.
Then i installed the server.After completing the installation i ll not find workbench.
Is workbench is necessary to create local database from the script file or we can use sqlYog  to create local database from the script file.

tell me which one is best workbench or SqlYog..?

if workbench is best then ,
then tell me how to get workbench for mysql-5.5.27-winx64 server.

Comment: You can always use the commandline tool `mysql` to run your SQL scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlyog is the best to create database or export from script file .  mysql work bench is not used for this purpose , it is basically used to reverse engineer any existing database and design a database . So use SQl yog to create local database ,from script file .

Mysql work bench wont come along with mysql , you can download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) . It is a separate tool

If you could setup a LAMP stack , you can use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) which is also a good tool to use.

Comment: @ aravind: thanks for your answer. I mysql if i run script file i got "Mysql server has gone away" error message why i am getting this error message

Comment: Where are you running this , what is the script that you are running , Is your mysql server service is running in your system ,

Comment: i run this in my system local mysql server using mysql workbench export/import option. my script file is *.sql format.mysql server is in start mode ly but i start run the script file then i got that error message

Comment: okay you are trying to import a file from mysql work bench , Are you expecting that script to create a database or you have already created a database and exporting data from script

Comment: CAn you try running it from command line mysql -u USER -p DATABASE < FILENAME.sql with this command

Comment: that script file define new database creation,table creation and inserting  records to that tables.

Comment: I think work bench expects you to create a database and export data to it , your script is taken that concern , then you have to use the command line or you have to remove the create database thing from your script and import it

Comment: you can go to command line and simply run "mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < FILENAME.sql"

Comment: in that command database means new database that i am going to create from the script..? username is root..?